# populating spinner based on another spinner selection

Tags: android, spinner

I have one spinner with a list of body parts eg. chest, legs, back. i also have string arrays for each body part with a list of exercises for that body part eg. for chest i have a string array called chest exercise with a selection of exercises like bench press, dumbbell press etc. 
So for example i would like to populate the second spinner with chest exercise if chest was selected or leg exercise if leg was selected. Any ides?

```
 String[] chestExercises = {"Flat Barbell Bench Press", "Incline Barbell Bench Press",
            "Decline Barbell Bench Press", "Flat Dumbbell Press", "incline Dumbbell Press", "Decline Dumbbell Press",
            "Cable Flys", "Dumbbell Flys",};


    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


   }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);



    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(record_workout.this,
                    "OnClickListener : " +
              "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())+
               "\nSpinner 2 : String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**All you need to do is check the spinner1 input, and based on that, set the array adapter which corresponds to spinner2 based on the user input matching a certain arraylist:**

I wrote this code for you to get a better idea, and have added some comments in it, so check those out too.

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    ArrayList<MyObject> Chest = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); // This is actually the list created from the HashMap
    ArrayList<MyObject> Knee = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); // This is actually the list created from the HashMap
    ArrayList<MyObject> Head = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); // This is actually the list created from the HashMap

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(record_workout.this,
                          "OnClickListener : " +
                          "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())+
                          "\nSpinner 2 : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = null;

            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().equals("Chest"){
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Chest);
            } else if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().equals("Knee"){ //INPUT = KNEE SO SET ADAPTER TO KNEE ARRAY LIST
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Knee);
            } else if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().equals("Head"){
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, head);
            }

            if (adapter != null) {
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I did here is I checked the input in the first spinner in your spinner listener. Then, I checked to see if it matched "head", "chest", or "Knee", and if it did, I set the `ArrayAdapter` for Spinner 2 to the corresponding `ArrayList`.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the code but i cant get it working. i edit the original post it now includes the array for chest exercise. so when chest is selected i would like to have that arrays contents appear

Comment: it does not work. I understand what you are trying to do but i dont understand this part :ArrayList<MyObject> Chest = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

Comment: That is an array list called Chest populated with your values that you want in the spinner when the user selects `chest`

Comment: it says "cannot resolve symbol 'MyObject' ". is this how i should be creating my arrays?   (sorry im very new to android)                                                                              ` String[] legExercises = {"Squat", "Leg Press", "Lunge", "Leg Extension", "Leg Curl", "Seated Calf Raise", "Standing Calf Raise"};
                final ArrayAdapter legAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, legExercises);`

Comment: @user3091082 Replace the word `MyObject` with String

Comment: @user3091082 Its fine if you are new to android, I'm here to help :) Let me know if you have any more questions, and dont be embarassed :)

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to String but now i also have a problem with this line     ` adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Knee); `                                             I tried replacing objectName with String but it says cannot resolve constructor

Comment: Okay, try just removing the whole `<ObjectName>` thing, so it should be: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Knee);` Let me know what hapens